# Foundation 6 sticky nav overlay

Tags: navigation

I'm using [this solution](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/36690-how-to-create-a-sticky-top-bar-on-foundation-6) to create a sticky nav in Foundation 6. The thing it's not doing that I'd like it to do is to overlay the underlying content, so that the background image from the section below is actually visible underneath the nav on page load, rather than only on scroll.

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/rtourtelot/pen/obBQqE

```
    <div id="page">
  <div class="top-bar-container" data-sticky-container>
    <div class="sticky" data-sticky data-options="anchor: page; marginTop: 0; stickyOn: small;">
      <div class="top-bar">
        <div class="row column">
          <div class="top-bar-left">
            <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
              <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
              <li class="has-submenu">
                <a href="#">One</a>
                <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
                  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="top-bar-right">
            <ul class="menu">
              <li>
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
              </li>
              <li>
                <button type="button" class="button">Search</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="hero large-12-columns">
    </div>

    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="callout">
        <h3>We&rsquo;re stoked you want to try Foundation! </h3>
        <p>To get going, this file (index.html) includes some basic styles you can modify, play around with, or totally destroy to get going.</p>
        <p>Once you've exhausted the fun in this document, you should check out:</p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
            <p><a href="http://foundation.zurb.com/docs">Foundation Documentation</a>
              <br />Everything you need to know about using the framework.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
            <p><a href="http://zurb.com/university/code-skills">Foundation Code Skills</a>
              <br />These online courses offer you a chance to better understand how Foundation works and how you can master it to create awesome projects.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
            <p><a href="http://foundation.zurb.com/forum">Foundation Forum</a>
              <br />Join the Foundation community to ask a question or show off your knowlege.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-4 medium-4 medium-push-2 columns">
            <p><a href="http://github.com/zurb/foundation">Foundation on Github</a>
              <br />Latest code, issue reports, feature requests and more.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="large-4 medium-4 medium-pull-2 columns">
            <p><a href="https://twitter.com/ZURBfoundation">@zurbfoundation</a>
              <br />Ping us on Twitter if you have questions. When you build something with this we'd love to see it (and send you a totally boss sticker).</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-8 medium-8 columns">
      <h5>Here&rsquo;s your basic grid:</h5>
      <!-- Grid Example -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
          <div class="primary callout">
            <p><strong>This is a twelve column section in a row.</strong> Each of these includes a div.callout element so you can see where the columns are - it's not required at all for the grid.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
          <div class="primary callout">
            <p>Six columns</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
          <div class="primary callout">
            <p>Six columns</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-4 columns">
          <div class="primary callout">
            <p>Four columns</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-4 columns">
          <div class="primary callout">
            <p>Four columns</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-4 columns">
          <div class="primary callout">
            <p>Four columns</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr />

      <h5>We bet you&rsquo;ll need a form somewhere:</h5>
      <form>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <label>Input Label</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="large-12.columns" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
            <label>Input Label</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="large-4.columns" />
          </div>
          <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
            <label>Input Label</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="large-4.columns" />
          </div>
          <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
            <div class="row collapse">
              <label>Input Label</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="small-9.columns" class="input-group-field" />
                <span class="input-group-label">.com</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <label>Select Box</label>
            <select>
              <option value="husker">Husker</option>
              <option value="starbuck">Starbuck</option>
              <option value="hotdog">Hot Dog</option>
              <option value="apollo">Apollo</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
            <label>Choose Your Favorite</label>
            <input type="radio" name="pokemon" value="Red" id="pokemonRed">
            <label for="pokemonRed">Radio 1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="pokemon" value="Blue" id="pokemonBlue">
            <label for="pokemonBlue">Radio 2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
            <label>Check these out</label>
            <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox1">Checkbox 1</label>
            <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox2">Checkbox 2</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <label>Textarea Label</label>
            <textarea placeholder="small-12.columns"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
      <h5>Try one of these buttons:</h5>
      <p><a href="#" class="button">Simple Button</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#" class="success button">Success Btn</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#" class="alert button">Alert Btn</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#" class="secondary button">Secondary Btn</a></p>
      <div class="callout">
        <h5>So many components, girl!</h5>
        <p>A whole kitchen sink of goodies comes with Foundation. Check out the docs to see them all, along with details on making them your own.</p>
        <a href="http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/" class="small button">Go to Foundation Docs</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In any case, I've tried using margin-top: -40px on the section below, but it's wonky, and doesn't work well. I've also tried making **data-margin-top=".1"** for siteNavStickyWrap, but that's kludgy as well.

Has anyone found a clean, stable way to have a sticky nav in Foundation 6 that automatically overlays the sticky nav over the underlying page content on load?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try to reset position of a .top-bar-container? now it's relative, that's why the picture goes straight after it, not underneath... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QygJjQ